# c++ switch vs. member function pointer vs. virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I am trying to analyze the trade offs between various methods of achieving polymorphism. I need a list of objects with some similarities and some differences in member functions. The options I see are as follows:

1. have a flag in each object, and a switch statement in each function.
   The value of the flag directs each object to its specific section of
   each function.
2. have an array of member function pointers in the object, which are
   assigned upon construction. Then, I call that function pointer to
   get the correct member function.
3. have an virtual base class with several derived classes. One
   drawback to this is that my list will now have to contain pointers,
   and not the objects themselves.

My understanding is that the pointer lookups from the list in option 3 will take longer than the member function lookups of option 2 because of the guaranteed proximity of member functions.

What are some of the benefits/drawbacks of these options? My priority is performance over readability. 
Is there any other method for polymorphism?

Comment: 1. Horrible, 2. Slightly less Horrible, 3. Your best bet, 4. Do you need the polymorphism? Often you can get around this by using templates...

Comment: "My priority is performance over readability." - so wrong. So horribly wrong. Even if you need performance, why are you reimplementing virtual functions manually, if the language already provides them (via polymorphism -- vtables anyone?)?

Comment: "My priority is performance over readability.". You should learn to benchmark/profile code before you have the right to say this sentence.

Comment: Oh and one more thing, you'll want it to be readable when you come to fix that critical bug that's preventing your production instance from running...

Comment: People commenting above. Sometimes performance *is* more important than readability, and I think it is rude to assume he or she hasn't already profiled. It's a valid question, don't down-vote because it conflicts with your narrow world-view of programming.

Comment: You didn't list the one approach that's both readable and likely faster than all 3: templates. You may also want to look at static polymorphism, i.e. CRTP.

Comment: @PeterAlexander Performance requires readability.  Or at least encapsulation.  Once the profiler shows where the performance problems are, you have to be able to modify the code to solve them.

Comment: @PeterAlexander, I didn't down-vote; but often these types of generic questions really imply the the OP hasn't thoroughly investigated the options (for example templates are not considered at all.) And any answers that will be provided are anecdotal at best. Barring the ability to provide a concrete and useful answer, all we can do is comment on the fallacies in the question (i.e. the belief that performant code is illegible.)

Comment: Anything one can say about performance here will depend on the
compiler and the machine the code is running on.  A switch may
or may not be faster than virtual function resolution, and which
is faster may depend on the individual processor.

Comment: @Nim If I've read the question correctly, the case he is considering involves runtime polymorphism, so templates aren't a solution.  It doesn't seem to fit the template patters (varying interface, same implementation) particularly well.

Comment: Templates aren't always a silver bullet, they have their drawbacks. When they are overly used in large applications, resulting code bloat can decrease performance significantly due to poor cache hit ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve faster polymorphism is through the [CRTP idiom and static polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template<typename T>
struct base
{
    void f()
    {
         static_cast<T*>( this )->f_impl();
    }
};

struct foo : public base<foo>
{
    void f_impl()
    {
       std::cout << "foo!" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct bar : public base<bar>
{
    void f_impl()
    {
       std::cout << "bar!" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct quux : public base<quux>
{
    void f_impl()
    {
       std::cout << "quux!" << std::endl;
    }
};


template<typename T>
void call_f( const base<T>& something )
{
    something.f();
}

int main()
{
    foo my_foo;
    bar my_bar;
    quux my_quux;

    call_f( my_foo );
    call_f( my_bar );
    call_f( my_quux );
}
```

This outputs:

> foo!
>   bar!
>   quux!

Static-polymorphism [performs far better than virtual dispatch](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/12/05/the-cost-of-dynamic-virtual-calls-vs-static-crtp-dispatch-in-c/), because **the compiler knows which function will be called at compile-time, and it could inline everything**.

Even if it provides dynamic binding, it cannot perform polymorphism in the common heterogeneous-container way, because every instance of the base class is a different type.
However, that could be achieved with something like [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html).

Answer (score 3):

1. *have a flag in each object, and a switch statement in each function. The value of the flag directs each object to its specific section of each function*

   OK, so this could make sense if very little code varies based on the flag.
   This minimises the amount of (duplicated) code which has to fit in cache, and avoids any function call indirection.  Under some circumstances these benefits could outweigh the extra cost of the switch statement.
2. *have an array of member function pointers in the object, which are assigned upon construction. Then, I call that function pointer to get the correct member function*

   You save one indirection (to the vtable), but also make your objects bigger so fewer fit in cache. It's impossible to say which will dominate, so you'll just have to profile, but it isn't an obvious win
3. *have an virtual base class with several derived classes. One drawback to this is that my list will now have to contain pointers, and not the objects themselves*

   If the your code paths are different enough that separating them completely is reasonable, this is the cleanest solution. If you need to optimise it, you can either use a specialised allocator to ensure they're sequential (even if not sequential in your container), or move the objects directly into your container using a clever wrapper similar to Boost.Any. You'll still get the vtable indirection, but I'd prefer this to #2 unless profiling shows it's really a problem.

So, there are several questions you should answer before you can decide:

1. how much code is shared, and how much varies?
2. how big are the objects, and will a table of inline function pointers materially affect your cache miss stats?

and, after you've answered those, you should just profile anyway.

Answer (score 2):

With a `switch` statement, if you want to add a new class then you need to modify everywhere where the class is switched on, which may be in various places in your code base. There may also be places outside your code base that need to be modified, but perhaps you know this isn't the case in this scenario.

With an array of member function pointers within each member, the only downside is that you duplicate that memory for every object. If you know there's only one or two "virtual" functions though then it's a good option.

As for virtual functions, you are right in that you have to heap allocate them (or manual manage the memory), but it is the most extensible option.

If you aren't after extensible, then (1) or (2) may be your best option. As always, the only way to tell is to measure. I know that many compilers will implement a switch statement in some cases by a jump table, which essentially comes out the same as a virtual function table. For small numbers of `case` statement they may just use binary search branching.

Measure!

Comment: `As for virtual functions, you are right in that you have to heap allocate them (or manual manage the memory)` Not true. You just need to pass the object by reference or pointer (or, obviously, call on it directly with its real static type). How the object was allocated is completely irrelevant. I do tonnes of polymorphic stuff with objects allocated on the stack. The worst thing is that Stroustrup has the same false statement in one of his FAQs. I guess that's where people keep repeating this from.